# jQuery watermark plugin disappearing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, watermark

I am in search for a good jQuery watermark plugin that work with ASP.NET and found [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/#Troubleshooting) and downloaded it and included in the head portion

```
<script src="js/jquery.watermark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have login and signup on same page and referencing them as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<%= (Login1.FindControl("UserName")).ClientID %>").watermark("Enter your Username");
            $("#<%= (Login1.FindControl("Password")).ClientID %>").watermark("Enter your Password");
            $("#<%= (CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName")).ClientID %>").watermark("Enter your Username");
            $("#<%= (CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Password")).ClientID %>").watermark("Enter your Password");
            $("#<%= (CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("ConfirmPassword")).ClientID %>").watermark("Enter your ConfirmPassword");
            $("#<%= (CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email")).ClientID %>").watermark("Enter your Email");
        });
    </script>
```

Now the problem is the watermark is showing very well for all the textboxes.If I try to login then the page will be doing `postback` then all the `watermark` from the `textboxes` `disappears`.

So what do I need to do in order not to remove all of them even though there is a postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this simple trick

```
<input type="text" value="Enter keyword here" 
 onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter keyword here'){this.value=''}" 
onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Enter keyword here'}" />
```

Or You can try HTML 5 placeholder

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Your first name...">
```

Comment: @Mujassir-Thanks for your reply.This is really the simplest and very effective one.

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh part of a page, the event bindings associated with the replaced elements are thrown out. You need to re-initialize the bindings to the replaced elements. You need to re-run the function inside *watermark* that does this.

Comment: @Diodeus-First thanks for your reply and Can you show me some code to start with.

Comment: Contact the author of the script.